# How to open bootstrap react dropdown manu on mouse hover?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working in a team project where we are using react bootstrap nav bar. We want the drop down manu to open on mouse hover. Couldn't find any satisfactory answer yet. Please help.

Comment: There are 2 kinds of bootstrap repo related on react. `react-bootstrap`, `reactstrap`. You seem to need to elaborate a little more on your question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Dropdown
      onMouseOver={() => setShow(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setShow(false)}
    >
      <Dropdown.Toggle className="main-style" id="dropdown-basic">
        Dropdown Button
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu show={show}>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/
i found that you can controll react-bootstrap Dropdown.Menu by show props

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for, not sure why the code is not running in the example looks ok to me. - and it works for me.